# Vertically Centre Text in NSSecureTextField with subclassing

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextfield

I'm trying to vertically centre text in my NSTextFields, but one of them is for a password, so it's a NSSecureTextField. I've set it's class to be [`MDVerticallyCenteredSecureTextFieldCell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624834/how-do-i-vertically-center-align-text-in-a-nstextfield) with the following implementation:

```
- (NSRect)adjustedFrameToVerticallyCenterText:(NSRect)frame {
    // super would normally draw text at the top of the cell
    NSInteger offset = floor((NSHeight(frame) - 
                              ([[self font] ascender] - [[self font] descender])) / 2);
    return NSInsetRect(frame, 0.0, offset+10);
}

- (void)editWithFrame:(NSRect)aRect inView:(NSView *)controlView
               editor:(NSText *)editor delegate:(id)delegate event:(NSEvent *)event {
    [super editWithFrame:[self adjustedFrameToVerticallyCenterText:aRect]
                  inView:controlView editor:editor delegate:delegate event:event];
}

- (void)selectWithFrame:(NSRect)aRect inView:(NSView *)controlView
                 editor:(NSText *)editor delegate:(id)delegate 
                  start:(NSInteger)start length:(NSInteger)length {

    [super selectWithFrame:[self adjustedFrameToVerticallyCenterText:aRect]
                    inView:controlView editor:editor delegate:delegate
                     start:start length:length];
}

- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)view {
    [super drawInteriorWithFrame:
     [self adjustedFrameToVerticallyCenterText:frame] inView:view];
}

-(void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    [super drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}
```

A similar subclass is already working for regular `NSTextFieldCell`s, just not secure versions of this. It seems like Apple has somehow protected these methods from being overridden.

Now the password field is the only one misaligned:

[image: misaligned "password" field]

Can anyone suggest a way get the `NSSecureTextFieldCell` subclass's methods to be called or another way to vertically centre the text field?

Answer (score 26):

Try using a regular NSTextField, with your NSSecureTextFieldCell subclass inside. I had the same problem and this combination worked.

Comment: Worked for me too :)

Answer (score 5):

You can create subclass of the `NSSecureTextField` like:

```
@implementation SubclassTextField

+ (Class)cellClass {
    return [SubclassTextFieldCell class];
}

@end
```

and the subclass of the cell:

```
@implementation SubclassTextFieldCell

- (NSRect)drawingRectForBounds:(NSRect)rect {
    // It will be working
    ...
}

...
@end
```

If you do so then methods from subclassed `NSSecureTextField` will start working.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Assigning a custom cell class in Interface Builder isn't sufficient. `-[NSSecureTextField initWithCoder:]` checks the decoded cell's class and will create a new instance if it doesn't match `+cellClass`.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do to vertically center the placeholder text in either an `NSTextField` or `NSSecureTextField` is check the "Uses Single Line Mode" checkbox in the Attributes inspector (Text Field section). If you're not using IB, you can set it programmatically like so:

```
[mySecureTextField.cell setUsesSingleLineMode:YES];
```