# Rounded corner on NSSecureTextFieldCell in OSX

Tags: macos

I have managed to subclass NSTextFieldCell to get rounded corners on NSTextField. I want to do the same for NSSecureTexField, but subclassing the NSSecureTextFieldCell is having no effect.

The `- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView { .. }` never gets invoked.

Has anyone been able to give rounder corners to NSSecureTextField? If so, what is the best approach to getting this done?

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.. In case anyone is looking for a solution..
Here is the link that pointed me to the correct answer.. along with the code snippet.

So the trick as mentioned is.. to add a regular textfield in IB.. but set its cell to be a sub-class of `CustomNSSecureTextFieldCell`

[Vertically Centre Text in NSSecureTextField with subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400686/vertically-centre-text-in-nssecuretextfield-with-subclassing?rq=1)

```
@interface CustomNSSecureTextFieldCell : NSSecureTextFieldCell

@end


@implementation CustomNSSecureTextFieldCell

- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {

    NSBezierPath *betterBounds = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cellFrame xRadius:CORNER_RADIUS yRadius:CORNER_RADIUS];
    [betterBounds addClip];
    [super drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
    if (self.isBezeled) {
        [betterBounds setLineWidth:2];
        [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.510 green:0.643 blue:0.804 alpha:1] setStroke];
        [betterBounds stroke];
    }
}
@end
```