# How to vertically align text of NSSecureTextField in swift for macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I created a sub class of NSSecureTextFieldCell named PasswordCellField and changed the class of NSSecureTextFieldCell to  PasswordCellField in attributes inspector but its not working. please anybody help me to out from it

here is my code:

```
import Cocoa

class PasswordCellField: NSSecureTextFieldCell{
    
    override func drawingRect(forBounds rect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
        
        var newRect = super.drawingRect(forBounds: rect)
        let textSize = self.cellSize(forBounds: rect)
        let heightDelta = newRect.size.height - textSize.height
        if heightDelta > 0 {
            newRect.size.height -= heightDelta
            newRect.origin.y += (heightDelta / 2)
        }
        return newRect
    }
    
    func adjustedFrame(toVerticallyCenterText rect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
        // super would normally draw text at the top of the cell
        var titleRect = super.titleRect(forBounds: rect)

        let minimumHeight = self.cellSize(forBounds: rect).height
        titleRect.origin.y += (titleRect.height - minimumHeight) / 2
        titleRect.size.height = minimumHeight

        return titleRect
    }

    override func edit(withFrame rect: NSRect, in controlView: NSView, editor textObj: NSText, delegate: Any?, event: NSEvent?) {
        super.edit(withFrame: adjustedFrame(toVerticallyCenterText: rect), in: controlView, editor: textObj, delegate: delegate, event: event)
    }

    override func select(withFrame rect: NSRect, in controlView: NSView, editor textObj: NSText, delegate: Any?, start selStart: Int, length selLength: Int) {
        super.select(withFrame: adjustedFrame(toVerticallyCenterText: rect), in: controlView, editor: textObj, delegate: delegate, start: selStart, length: selLength)
    }

    override func drawInterior(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        super.drawInterior(withFrame: adjustedFrame(toVerticallyCenterText: cellFrame), in: controlView)
    }

    override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        super.draw(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Hi Willeke, Its working for NSTextField when I inherited from NSTextFieldCell instead of NSSecureTextFieldCell. But its not working for secure field

Comment: What are the symptoms? Are the methods called?

Comment: See [Vertically Centre Text in NSSecureTextField with subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400686/vertically-centre-text-in-nssecuretextfield-with-subclassing)

Comment: @Willeke its not working for me