# UITextField vertical text alignment on transform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have a `UITextfield` & I am going to apply the vertical alignments to it(top,bottom,center). I done it correctly by setting the vertical alignment. But when I transform the textfield using `(-M_PI/2)` and apply bottom or center alignment, then it works fine but text in textfield is not visible to user.
If anyone knows the solution regarding this then please help me .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439099/how-do-i-vertically-center-uitextfield-text/23577643#23577643

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try may work for u

```
  textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

  textField.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
```

Comment: In viewDidLoad, I set the frame of textfield as (100,100,250,40) & then transform it. I think width set to height because of transforming the textfield & viceversa.

Comment: I didn't get u; 250 is width and 40 is height

Comment: UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmenCenter
UIControlContentVerticalAlignmenTop 
is it nor work for u

Comment: Code which I written is as follows - self.txtMessage = [[UITextField alloc] init];       self.txtMessage.frame = CGRectMake(430.0, 140.0, 250.0, 40.0);           self.txtMessage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2); [self.txtMessage1 setClipsToBounds:YES];   For top alignment, I written the following code & similarly to other.  txtcurrentTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;  txtcurrentTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmenCenter